# Why does Context.RewritePath maintain the query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

After reviewing the code below, I noticed that the call to [`Context.RewritePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d.aspx) is somehow not losing the query string, even though it is being called without a query string. Is there any documentation explaining why the query string is being maintained?

```
//URL relative path to ashx files is wrong to to path rewriting.
if (Request.Url.LocalPath.EndsWith(".ashx")) {
    Context.RewritePath(Request.Url.LocalPath
        .Substring(Request.Url.LocalPath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
}
```

**Edit:** I am not asking how to fix this; the code behaves correctly.  I am just asking for documentation of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially doing a Rewrite of the path, and in most cases, the query needs to be maintained to pass to the new Path.

Take for example a new document retrieval page named "getDocumentWithEnhancements.aspx" as opposed to the old "getDocument.aspx".  Both need a parameter to be useful, but you want the new one to be used.  A RewritePath would do the job, as it takes the query passed to the old, and passes to the new.  If you want to show some sort of error page or something, then instead you'd either use a redirect, or whatever page you're rewriting to will just ignore the querystring.

Why would you not want the query to be passed through?  What exactly are you using this for?  Maybe it's not the right function for what you need.

edit: There's an overloaded function taking 3 parameters, one of which is a querystring, which you could pass in as null to not use the querystring.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with my code; it is doing what I want.  I just could not find any documentation explicitly stating that the query string was maintained.  It does not strike me as completely obvious (i.e., obvious enough to justify not documenting it) that if I pass in no query string, it will use my existing one, so I was hoping to be able to find some official or semi-official documentation to that effect.